# Delphi How to Use UpArrow DownArrow to navigate

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a form with a TDBGrid and TClientDatabase.

I want to allow using the UpArrow or DownArrow to navigate in the database no matter which control has focus.

I set the Form.KeyPreview := true

This is the Form.OnKeyPress

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char); 
var Direction : Integer; 
begin    
   Direction := -1;    
   if Key = VK_UP then Direction := 1; {Previous}    
   if Key = VK_DOWN then Direction := 0; {Next}       
   if Direction <> -1 then    
   begin
      if Direction = 0 then cds1.Next else cds1.Prior;
      NextRecord; {Processes AfterScroll event}    
   end; 
end;
```

This gives me an error **E2008 Incompatible types**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Using `FormShortCut` seems to work well: `if ((Msg.CharCode = VK_UP) or (Msg.CharCode = VK_DOWN)) then
    begin
      SelectNext(ActiveControl, (Msg.CharCode = VK_DOWN), True);
      Handled := True;
    end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Key is Char, but VK_UP is integer constant. You have to use these constants in KeyDown event handler that has parameter `Key:Word`
2. Moreover, arrow keys don't generate OnKeyPress event (it is intended for alphanumeric keys)
3. From help: Navigation keys (Tab, BackTab, the arrow keys, and so on) **are unaffected by KeyPreview** because they do not generate keyboard events

Comment: So not much use with KeyPreview then

Comment: This a helpful answer. Thank you MBo.

Comment: @Chuck To get anywhere you need to follow Sertac's advice in the dupe